# Why Can't I receive POST value of dynamic added input text box?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I add input text box dynamically and trying to pass values using POST method but everytime I submit the form, I only receive the first value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_ele() {

    // For Internet Explorer
        try {
            el = document.createElement("<input type='text' name='cat[]' >");
        }
        // For other browsers
        catch (e) {
            el = document.createElement('input');
            el.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            el.setAttribute('name', 'cat[]');
        }

    document.getElementById('cate').appendChild(el);
    }
</script>



<form action='submit.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div id='cate' style='width:100px'>
<input type='text' name='cat[]' value='kjkj'>
</div>
</form>
<a href='#' onClick=\"return add_ele()\">Add Another</a>
```

Submit page:

```
$p_cat = $_POST['cat'];
foreach ($p_cat as $p_cate ) {

echo "$p_cate . <br>";
}
```

Someone please guide.

Comment: Is this your complete code ? Where is your form tag ?

Comment: form tag is included in the original code.

Comment: where are you declaring the <form> tag?

Comment: `<div id='cate'>` is inside of a `<form>`? We can't see the rest of the HTML.  Also, use the `var` keyword so you don't add `el` to the global namespace:  `var el = ..`

Comment: <div id='cate'> is inside of a <form>

Comment: Your code, exactly as above but with the form element & submit button, & without the `\"` in the `onclick` attribute value, works for me (using Firefox or Chrome). Are you seeing the elements created on the page? Are you using POST?

Comment: yes yes but I cant see the posted values other than the first one. and when i say echo count($p_cat), it says 1 although I had more than 1 text box

Comment: tried on FF as well. it does not work

Comment: I suspect there's more to this than meets the eye. Did you do a var_dump( $_POST ) ?

Comment: never mind, I had a table tag opened that I forgot to close. Everything worked fine after closing the table tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your complete code, you're not setting the `<input>`'s `value` attribute, so there's nothing to submit. Here's a modified (and cleaned up) example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addElement() {
        var  input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'cat[]');
        input.setAttribute('value', 'some value');
        document.getElementById('cate').appendChild(input);

        // We need to return false so the href isn't followed.
        return false;
    }

</script>

<form action="submit.php" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="cate" style="width: 100px">
        <input type="text" name="cat[]" value="kjkj">
    </div>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="return addElement()">Add Another</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't need a value, if there's no value then it will still show up in the $_POST array, it just won't have a value, it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double-quotes in HTML markup ( not apostrophes ). This should work :

```html
el = document.createElement('<input type="text" name="cat[]" >');
```

I guess you have to use double-quotes in html markup. This should work :